# $\dim(\ker((A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I))) \geq \dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) + \dim(\ker(A-\psi I))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a complex square matrix and $\lambda$ and $\psi$ its eigenvalues. We can easily prove this inequality:
$$\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I)) \geq \dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) + \dim(\ker(A-\psi I))$$
by choosing bases for $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ and $\ker(A-\psi I)$ and using $(A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I)$ on them.

But when are the dimensions equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the dimensions are always equal.  Because we generally have $\dim \ker(AB) = \dim\ker B + \dim(\operatorname{im}(B) \cap \ker A)$, it suffices to note that the image of $(A - \psi I)$ contains the kernel of $(A - \lambda I)$.

To that effect, suppose that $x \in \ker(A - \lambda I)$, so that $Ax = \lambda x$. It follows that $(A - \psi I)x = (\lambda - \psi)x$, which means that $x = (A - \psi I)y$ where $y = (\lambda - \psi)^{-1}x$. So, $x$ is indeed an element of the image of $A - \psi I$.

Comment: Thanks. After reading your answer i realized i have made a typo in the question. It should be $dim(ker((−)(−)))$ instead of $dim(ker(−)(−))$. Since that is a different question, should i leave this as it is and ask another one?

Comment: I don’t see the difference

Answer (score 0):

I take OP's statement
*We can easily prove this inequality*
$\dim(\ker((A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I))) \geq \dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) + \dim(\ker(A-\psi I))$
as a given

we also know that
$\dim(\ker((A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I))) \leq \dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) + \dim(\ker(A-\psi I))$
**by Sylvester's Rank Inequality.**

This implies
$\dim(\ker((A-\lambda I)(A-\psi I))) =\dim(\ker(A-\lambda I)) + \dim(\ker(A-\psi I))$

(the standard for of Sylvester's Rank Inequality of course involves Rank.  But negating, then adding 2n to each side and applying rank-nullity gives this other form)